# Handle custom cookie expiration event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I am creating a cookie inside a .net core application, and I want to find a way to handle the expiring event of this cookie on the "server side", not on the client side using js.

Basically, I want to call a method when the cookie expires. Note the fact that dis cookie is not an authentication cookie or some cookie generated by a service. Is a complete custom cookie created by me.

I have looked into some similar issues reported here, but the answers found there are solutions for authentication cookies and they don't suite me.

Comment: HttpWebResponse has a cookie class with Expires and Expired properties

Comment: Read this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

Comment: My problem is not about creating/reading/adding cookies on a response/request. My problem is the fact that i don't know how to add a "callback" on that cookie. I want to add on that cookie a method that will be called when the cookie expires.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie expiration isn't a one-time event . On each request the client can send cookie to server side . Server side will not notice whether your cookie is expired unless checking the cookie property on each request using middleware or somewhere  .

That means even you enable cookie expire time validation logic on server side , but if your client doesn't send request to server , server side will not know whether your cookie expires . That also depends on browsers , some browsers will delete the cookie if it expires .