# How to Handle Cookie Expiration in Asp.Net Core 7?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm new to Authentication using Cookies and Claims.

So i have followed the offical Microsoft Documentaion on how to apply authentication in an Asp.Net Core 7 Application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie
(my code is exactly a replica from this documentation)

and it worked, but i am still facing a challange,
I have a table in Database **[Login_Log**],
that stores UserData, his Login_DateTime, his **Logout_DateTime**, and Last_Interaction_DateTime.

- I Add a new record to the table with DataTime.Now as Login_DateTime, (and add the UserData of course) --> Done
- I store the UserData in a Claim in the Cookies. --> Done
- I Added [Authorize] attribute on each Action Method except the login action method. --> Done
- I Added my custom logic to Authenticate the user in CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents.**ValidatePrincipal()** --> Done
- I Update the Last_Interaction_DateTime cell record in the database on each Authentication with a new DataTime.Now. --> Done

-- Now i can't find a proper way to insert (update) the **Logout_DateTime** in the database
I have done my seach for almost two weeks and didn't find a satisfying answer.

I understand that the cookies are Client Side and that the Authentication happens on the Server Side.
still,
**How to execute a Custom Code/Logic on Cookie Expiration**

Is their a way for an Ajax request to be send just before cookie expiration ?
Can the server side Session Storage keep track of the cookie expiration ?
Somethig else better ?

Thank you in advance for you help.

I tried these answers,
[How to handle cookie expiration in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890172/how-to-handle-cookie-expiration-in-asp-net-core)
[Handle custom cookie expiration event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711491/handle-custom-cookie-expiration-event)

Comment: First of all what kind of authentication mechanism are you using? If it is asp.net core Identity then within [`Logout.cshtml.cs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVz3L.png) file you would seen a method called `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();` before executing this statement, above of this,  you can pass the user ID and execute your insert and upate statement. Please [`refer to this way`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVz3L.png).  If you need further assistance on this please, feel free to share.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Md Farid Uddin Kiron,  
I am **not** using (.net core identity framwork), I created my own custom authentication logic from scratch, using the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie),  
Also i can register the **Logout_DateTime** if the user logged out willingly (something similar to your comment), However my question is when the user leave his browser open for more than 20 min. with no actions, so his cookie will expire on the client side, _Then What ?_

Comment: Well, if the user closed the browser, we can check the cookie `IsPersistent` option, usually we cannot detect if user close the brower, but IsPersistent` can be useful from server side.